# can't display 0 in grand total input box when the amount is negative value

Tags: javascript, html

**Question:** If the calculated grand total is a negative value, set it to zero instead. If the calculated grand total is a negative value, set it to zero instead. Additionally, the
user should be alerted that an error has occurred. You may use the appropriate medium
(i.e., prompt box, paragraph text under the table, etc.) to carry out this function.

I'm trying to do this in my code but seems like it is not working right. When grand total is lesser than 0 it should display zero on the grand total input box.

---

**This is my html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="book-order.css">
  </head>
  
  <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>

  <body class="background">
  
    <script src="book-order.js"></script>
    
    <table id="head">
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Book Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book1_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book1_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="theProduct" id="book1_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book2_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book2_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book2_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="numnber" name="unit price" id="book3_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book3_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book3_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>4</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book4_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book4_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book4_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>5</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book5_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book5_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book5_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="footer">
        <td colspan="5">
          <input 
            type="Submit" 
            id="click" 
            onclick="calculateTotal()" 
            value="Calculated Grand Total Price" 
            style="font-size: 18px;"
          >
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input 
            type="number" 
            name="total" 
            class="total" 
            id="grandtotal" 
            value="0.00" 
            style="width: 300px; height: 40px; font-weight: bolder; font-size: larger;" 
            disabled
          />
          
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input style="display:none" type="button" id="button" class="btn" value="Discount 10%" onclick="newGrandTotal()">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="Index.html">Go back to home</a>
    <br/>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

**This is my javascript:**

```js
function calculateTotal() {

  const NumberOfBooks = 5;
  
  for (let i = 1; i <= NumberOfBooks; ++i) {
    document.getElementById("book" + i + "_price").value =
      (document.getElementById("book" + i + "_price").value / 1).toFixed(2);
  }
  
  // row 1
  var price1 = document.getElementById("book1_price").value;
  var quan1 = document.getElementById("book1_quan").value;
  var total1 = document.getElementById("book1_total");
  total1.value = (price1 * quan1).toFixed(2);
  
  // row 2 
  var price2 = document.getElementById("book2_price").value;
  var quan2 = document.getElementById("book2_quan").value;
  var total2 = document.getElementById("book2_total");
  total2.value = (price2 * quan2).toFixed(2);

  // row 3 
  var price3 = document.getElementById("book3_price").value;
  var quan3 = document.getElementById("book3_quan").value;
  var total3 = document.getElementById("book3_total");
  total3.value = (price3 * quan3).toFixed(2);

  // row 4 
  var price4 = document.getElementById("book4_price").value;
  var quan4 = document.getElementById("book4_quan").value;
  var total4 = document.getElementById("book4_total");
  total4.value = (price4 * quan4).toFixed(2);

  // row 5 
  var price5 = document.getElementById("book5_price").value;
  var quan5 = document.getElementById("book5_quan").value;
  var total5 = document.getElementById("book5_total");
  total5.value = (price5 * quan5).toFixed(2);

  // grandtotal
  var grandtotal = document.getElementById("grandtotal");

  fulltotal = parseFloat(total1.value) + parseFloat(total2.value) + parseFloat(total3.value) + 
    parseFloat(total4.value) + parseFloat(total5.value);
  grandtotal.value = fulltotal.toFixed(2);
  //error
  if (fulltotal < 0) {
    alert("An error has occurred : Please enter positive values only.");
    document.getElementById("grandtotal")[0].value = 0;
  }
  
  checkGrandTotal();
  
}

function checkGrandTotal() {
  var value = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
  
  if (value > 250) {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
  }
}


function newGrandTotal() {
  var total = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
  var newtotal = total - (total / 10);
  
  alert("new grand total is :" + newtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: what result are you getting if it's not zero, and are we talking about the `fulltotal` or the `grandtotal`?

Comment: @Kinglish i want the answer to be in 0 when the total of everything is less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

if I am getting this right, you don't need Unit Price to be less than 0 ever.
Which is pretty easy to handle using HTML.

add the **min=0** attribute on the input tags

```html
<input type = "number" name = "unit price" id="book5_price" placeholder = "0.00" min=0>
```

Comment: Didnt work, i want the answer to be 0 when the total of everything is less than 0/negative values.

Comment: The min attribute won't prevent a script from inserting a negative number or user typing in. It only affects the counter arrows

Comment: in that case just wrap the **total** variable in **Math.abs()**.

eg: `Math.abs(-1)`

Comment: i want the user typing in negative values and show an alert box when the Calculate grand total price is clicked, when the user press ok, the value of the grand total must be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Math.max` function - it will return the largest of the two (either the total if it is bigger than 0, or 0 - if the total is negative)

```
total = Math.max(0, total);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were numerous little errors, like anytime you get a value from an input element it will always be text, so to add it you need to convert to a number. In the code below you'll see `+` right before `element.value` items - that little `+` is actually a shorthand notation to tell JS to treat that as a number. I also saw you wanted to do a loop, which was a good idea, so I show how to do that.

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  const NumberOfBooks = 5;
  let sum_total = 0;
  let grandtotal = document.getElementById("grandtotal");

  for (let i = 1; i <= NumberOfBooks; ++i) {
    let bprice = "book" + i + "_price",
      bquan = "book" + i + "_quan",
      btotal = "book" + i + "_total";

    let item_price = +document.getElementById(bprice).value
    let item_quantity = +document.getElementById(bquan).value

    let total = (item_price * item_quantity).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById(btotal).value = total
    sum_total += +total;
  }
  if (sum_total < 0) {
    alert("An error has occurred : Please enter positive values only.");
  }
  sum_total = Math.max(0, sum_total);
  grandtotal.value = sum_total.toFixed(2);
  checkGrandTotal();
}

function checkGrandTotal() {
  var value = +document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
  if (value > 250) {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
  }
}

// not sure what this function is for
function newGrandTotal() {
  var total = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
  var newtotal = total - (total / 10);
  alert("new grand total is :" + newtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
<table id="head">
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Book Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover middle">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="type">
        <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book1_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book1_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="theProduct" id="book1_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover middle">
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="type">
        <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book2_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book2_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book2_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover middle">
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="type">
        <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="numnber" name="unit price" id="book3_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book3_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book3_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover middle">
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="type">
        <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book4_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book4_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book4_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover middle">
    <td>5</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="type">
        <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book5_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book5_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book5_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="footer">
    <td colspan="5"><input type="Submit" id="click" onclick="calculateTotal()" value="Calculated Grand Total Price" style="font-size: 18px;"></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="number" name="total" class="total" id="grandtotal" value="0.00" style="width: 300px; height: 40px; font-weight: bolder; font-size: larger;" disabled/>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input style="display:none" type="button" id="button" class="btn" value="Discount 10%" onclick="newGrandTotal()">
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="Index.html">Go back to home</a>
<br/>
```

Comment: this works, but my Unit Price round to 2 decimal stop working.

Comment: i want my unit price to be rounded to 2 decimal when calculated.

Comment: the 2 decimal works for the first row only when click.

Comment: Ok, i updated the whole tamale. It needed some tlc, please see my updated answer

Comment: Function newgrandTotal is another task, is where like grand total is over 250, a button will  pop out to give a discount of 10%

Comment: ok, updated with full snippet. The issue again was in the string/number conversions. `toFixed()` turns the number into a string, so when we add the total we have to convert that number again to a number. This code works now, pls review